# PHP unable to take files of specified file size

Tags: php

**I want to get a text file upto size 20 Mb via browser.**

My php code is:

```
$allowedExts = array("txt");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$file_name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

if ((
   ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5243000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{ echo "Uploaded : " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";}

else {echo "Invalid file";}
```

**Note: my php ini settings are :**

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "20M");
ini_set("memory_limit", "32M");
ini_set("post_max_size","20M");
```

**but My browser throwing : Invalid File. even for 3 Mb file (*less than 2 Mb is working fine*)

Extension is .txt only,

I am  sure extension is not a problem.**
What might be the one and solution for it?

**UPDATE:

my PHP.ini says: Maximum allowed size for uploaded files. upload_max_filesize = 20M

but my php info(); still says: upload_max_filesize  local 2M    master 2M**

Comment: try `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: check the actual values of $_FILES with `var_dump($_FILES["file"]);`

Comment: It gives :
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "a.txt" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } Invalid file

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal print_r($_FILES); gives: Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => a.txt [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) ) Invalid file

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the `upload_max_filesize` variable using `ini_set` (as you can see in this list: [List of php.ini directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)). Change the php.ini configuration instead.

Comment: my PHP.ini says:  Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 5M

Comment: @Nari2 It could be overwritten by your .htaccess or other files as shown here: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure below things with print_r($_FILES)

1) $_FILES["file"]["type"] exact match to "text/plain"

2) $_FILES["file"]["size"] is less than 5243000

3) $extension value is txt ( Caps matter in this case )

4) check all the settings with ini_get after ini_set to make sure that settings has been changed

5) If still is ok then please past your print_r($_FILES) output here

Comment: It gives : array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "a.txt" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } Invalid file

Comment: please do the print_r not var_dump

Comment: print_r($_FILES); gives: Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => a.txt [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) ) Invalid file

Comment: what server you use? nginx?

Comment: ini_set('max_input_time', 200);

ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "8M");

Please use these lines of code where form loads and form submit

Comment: if you have still issue then print your phpinfo and give us url of that becuase it seems your upload_max_filesize is not increased using ini_set

Comment: @MichaelLivach Windows 7, IIS 7.5

Comment: I have no experience with iis, but googling says that iss has maxAllowedContentLength parameter [here](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits) and [here](http://pyd.io/f/topic/solved-instructions-for-uploading-and-downloading-of-large-files-on-iis7-5/)

Comment: @Pankaj php info still says : upload_max_filesize local 2M master 2M

Comment: @Nari2 so can you try once with less than 2 MB file

Comment: @Pankaj yeah it took 1.98 mb file.

Comment: @nari, so you have needed to increase upload_max_filesize using php value in htaccess, or using ini_set or using hosting provider

Comment: @Pankaj where is .htaccess file located?

Comment: @nari this is located in the root directory of your code , where your main file of code exists like index.php, index.html etc



php_value post_max_size 20M


php_value upload_max_filesize 20M

Comment: @Pankaj I'm working on windows IIS 7.5 not apache. I guess, I don't have .htaccess file.

Comment: @nari I have no idea about windows IIS, i am comfortable with apache, Sorry.

Comment: @Pankaj may be you can answer [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959042/apache2-unable-to-start-after-editing-httpd-conf-for-php-activation) for my another server.